# What does "Well, the staff, please" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Schindler's List (1993), in front of Nazi officials, a Jewess approaches and haltingly wishes Oskar,
bringing along an even younger girl carrying a homemade cake:

> Jewess: On behalf of the workers, sir, I wish for you a happy
> birthday.
>
> Young Girl: Happy birthday
>
> Oskar: **Well, the staff, please**. Thank you very much for the lovely
> cake.

What does "Well, the staff, please" mean?

Comment: In [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpxWq-hhoxE) it isn't clear what Oskar says, perhaps "Well one of the staff **cakes**."

Comment: Be wary that [some dictionaries](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/jewess) nowadays flag the word "Jewess" as dated at best, and offensive at worst.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELL isn't a transcription service. Particularly for syntactically meaningless movie dialogue snippets where all most of us would have to work with is a line from a subtitle file. Of a verbal interaction between two characters NEITHER OF WHOM ARE SUPPOSED TO BE NATIVE ANGLOPHONES IN THE FIRST PLACE.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica It's from subtitles

Comment: I know that! I've just gone to the trouble of checking both the subtitle AND the relevant bit in the movie (which is easier for me than for most people here). But imho it's not a suitable type of question for ELL, as explained by my closevote comment. And I won't deny that I'm predisposed to be harsh here because I'm one of those people who finds "Jewess" pointlessly offensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the transcript doesn't convey the rhythm and context well.

Oskar and the other Germans are having a rather drunken celebration of Oskar's birthday, when the two young Jewish workers arrive with the cake.  As you say the girls are (reasonably) rather intimidated and are very nervous. They speak very formally "On behalf of the workers..."

Oskar is relaxed and he has been drinking.  He exclaims "Well!"  (an exclamation of surprise).  "The staff [are here]"  (The staff meaning the workers). "Please [come in and present your cake]"  He then kisses both girls (the old one, on the lips).

So the overall meaning is a much shorter version of:

> "Oh my goodness, the workers have come with cake, please come in."